# Using IdentityServer3 to secure a Nancy API with JS access

Tags: c#, nancy, identityserver3

I'm currently redeveloping a site, which will consist of three projects - an API(using Nancy), a web client and an identity system(using IdentityServer3) with the aim to keep all 3 as decoupled as possible.

I'm totally new to IdentityServer3, and my knowledge of token-based authentication is middling at best.

Now I've got the logging in aspect down, with an access token holding a number of claims:

```
public Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain, Username, Password))
        {
            if (!principalContext.ValidateCredentials(context.UserName, context.Password))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

            using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, context.UserName))
            {
                if (userPrincipal == null)
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }

                var user = new AuthenticateResult(userPrincipal.Sid.ToString(), context.UserName, _claimsRepository.List(userPrincipal.Sid.ToString()));

                context.AuthenticateResult = user;
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

And using a modified example of the IdentityServer3 example JS code I call the API:

```
client.processSigninResponse().then(function (response) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:56568/api/v1/test',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            console.log(response);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + response.access_token);
        }
    }).then(function () {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(arguments);
    }, function () {
        console.log('failed');
        console.log(arguments);

    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    log(err);
});
```

However, when I catch this with Nancy:

```
public TestModule() : base("api/v1/test")
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters =>
        {
            var user = Context.GetMSOwinUser();
            return HttpStatusCode.OK;
        };
    }
```

The user isn't authenticated, and there are no claims. The token is being sent over though.

I'm referencing Microsoft.Owin, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Microsoft,Owin.Security, Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Nancy.Owin and Nancy.MSOwinSecurity and my startup class looks like:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseNancy();
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming I've missed something pretty fundamental out, so any pointers towards anything boneheaded I'm doing/not doing would be appreciated!

Comment: Anything in your CurrentUser? If not, do you use the RequiresAuthentication() for your module?

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Authentication-overview

Comment: I don't see any middleware that validates the identityserver token.

Comment: @john-korsnes - I've got all module-level authentication switched off until I've got I've got a populated MSOwinUser.

Comment: @leastprivilege - I've switched out the UseOAuthBearerAuthentication in the API for UseIdentityServer, however I'm unsure as what factory settings to set for just validation rather than replicating what I already have in the Authentication project.

Thank you both for the advice so far.

Comment: Figured it out! I needed to use UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication. Knew it'd be something pretty fundamental I'd missed out :)

Comment: Hmm... All this does in the end, is to use the UseOauthBearerAuthentication mw. Must be your options then.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/blob/master/source/AccessTokenValidation/IdentityServerBearerTokenValidationMiddleware.cs#L73